# Json Ajax and php file upload

Tags: php, json, ajax

Hie team, i would like help with the following Code. i wanna submit form with input text and file fields. The html form submits data on form submit, then after that the data is sent to create_news.php. but the page is not submitting images and i am failing to decode the file feild

```html
<form id="articles_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Title" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" id="datepicker-autoclose" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calender"></i></span>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Image Cover</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="file" id="file" placeholder="Article Cover" name="file" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea id="editor" required name="content" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>


  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add New Article
                                        </button>


</form>
```

Iam using php, ajax and json.. having two pages one is the javascript file and sending data to a php file for processing

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#articles_form', function() {

  // get form data
  var form_data = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject());

  // submit form data to api
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/myzimbiz/admin/process/create_news.php',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: form_data,
    dataType: 'json', //tell the system the type of data and it is stored in ddata

    success: function(data) {
      //give feedback
      alert(data.message);

      $("#articles_form").trigger('reset'); //reset form


    },
    error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
      // show error to console
      console.log(xhr, resp, text);
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

This is my create_news.php where upload is being processed, i am failing to decode the file fields.

```
<?php

// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");


//include the orm redbean file
include '../db.php';
// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

echo json_encode(array("message" => $data->file->name));

//move file
$stamp = time();
$uploaddir = '../images/';

$save_folder = 'images/';

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . '-' . $stamp . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $path = $save_folder.'-' . $stamp . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
} else {
    $path = "images/placeholder.png";
}

if(
    !empty($data->title) &&
    !empty($data->date) &&
    !empty($data->content) &&
    !empty($data->file)
)
{
    R::begin();
    try {
        //set task in database
        $article = R::dispense('about');
        $article->title = $data->title;
        $article->date = $data->date;
        $article->content = $data->content;
        $article->file = $data->file;
        $id = R::store($article);

        // set response code - 201 created
        http_response_code(201);
        // tell the user
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Created successfully."));
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == 23000) {
            R::rollback();
        }
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Duplicated data."));
    }

}else{
    // set response code - 503 service unavailable
    http_response_code(503);

    // tell the user
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to add content."));
}
?>
```

Comment: Try dumping `$data` to see what's in it.

Comment: `$_FILES` will not be populated because all your upload data is in JSON format. You never transfer the file. If you want to use all-JSON you'd have to explicitly get the file data and base64-encode it to a string and set it as a property of your JSON object.

Comment: But this seems like over-complicating things. A more conventional and [well-documented approach](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&ei=sApsXOHrBquX1fAPi5S74A8&q=jquery+upload+file+and+JSON&oq=jquery+upload+file+and+JSON&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2421.2697..3231...0.0..0.126.472.0j4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.mBq3D9RCsZQ) is to use a multi-part request and use FormData on the client-side to construct a request containing both the binary image data and the JSON data.

Comment: @ThisBoyPerforms OP is not trying to use `$data` to access the file data (look more closely at the code!). That's a good thing though, because it won't be there. Unfortunately it won't be in `$_FILES` either, as my comments above explain.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
 var form_data = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject());
```

To

```
var form_data = new FormData($("#articles_form")[0]);
```

Then your ajax setup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){ 
        $('#articles_form').on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();


            var form_data = new FormData($("#articles_form")[0]);
            form_data.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({

                url: 'http://localhost/myzimbiz/admin/process/create_news.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: form_data,
                dataType: 'json',
                encode: true,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) {
                  //give feedback
                  alert(data.message);

                  $("#articles_form").trigger('reset'); //reset form


                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                  // show error to console
                  console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }

            });
        });

    });
```

Sever.

```
    <?php
//include the orm redbean file
include '../db.php';
// get posted data

//move file
$stamp     = time();
$uploaddir = '../images/';

$save_folder = 'images/';

$title   = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : null;
$date    = isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : null;
$content = isset($_POST['content']) ? $_POST['content'] : null;
$file    = isset($_FILES['file']) ? $_FILES['file'] : null;


$uploadfile = $uploaddir . '-' . $stamp . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $path = $save_folder . '-' . $stamp . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
} else {
    $path = "images/placeholder.png";
}
R::begin();
try {
    //set task in database
    $article          = R::dispense('about');
    $article->title   = $title;
    $article->date    = $date;
    $article->content = $content;
    $article->file    = $file;
    $id               = R::store($article);

    // set response code - 201 created
    http_response_code(201);
    // tell the user
    echo json_encode(array(
        "message" => "Created successfully."
    ));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 23000) {
        R::rollback();
    }
    echo json_encode(array(
        "message" => "Duplicated data."
    ));
    http_response_code(503);
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, how then do i decode the $_FILES from json on the processing page

Comment: You remove all those json on the server side and process like you do when you proccess form normally.  The only thing you need as json is the response from the server

Comment: so i can data using $_POST and $_FILES

Comment: @Jeche yes just use those then when you want to return output just echo json_encode()

Comment: sorry i am failing to get you, isnt if i use post and files i will be good enough..